# Invoke-Command in Workflow sequence

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

Please help to get Invoke-Command working. It says -ScriptBlock parameter is null. It seems RegHomePage() function is not available in InlineScript{}.

```
function RegHomePage (){
get-item -path Registry::"HKEY_USERS\*\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" | `
Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_."Start Page" -ne $null} | Set-ItemProperty -Name "Start Page" -Value "about:blank"
}

$creds = Get-Credential -Credential value\wadmin
workflow foreachtest
{
    param([Parameter(mandatory=$true)][string[]]$computers)

    foreach -parallel -throttlelimit 20 ($computer in $computers)
    {
        sequence
        {
            $isPing = Test-Connection -count 1 $computer -quiet
            if($isPing){                
                $isWSMan  = [bool](Test-WSMan $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
            }
            if($isWSMan){
                InlineScript{
                    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $USING:computer -ScriptBlock ${function:RegHomePage}
                    } -PSComputerName $computer
                echo "$computer OK"
            }
            Else{
                $Workflow:out += "$computer`r`n"
                echo "$computer FAILED"
            }       

        }

    }
    Out-File .\offline.txt -InputObject $out
}

foreachtest -computers (Get-Content .\comps.txt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have a few issues with this inlineScript block.

- Dont provide the PSComputerName parameter since you are already running a job on each computer. There is no need to reference other systems here.
- I would suggest using Write-Output instead of echo (use powershell native commands)
- Move the function within the inlinescript to bring it in scope of each iteration.

```
workflow testing {
    foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers) {
        sequence {
            inlinescript {
                function RegHomePage {
                    Get-Item -path Registry::"HKEY_USERS\*\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" | `
                    Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_."Start Page" -ne $null} | Set-ItemProperty -Name "Start Page" -Value "about:blank"
                }
                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $using:computer -ScriptBlock ${Function:RegHomePage}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is what I tested with.

```
workflow testingWF {
    Param ([string[]] $computers)

    foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers) {
        sequence {
            InlineScript {
                function testFunc {
                  Param($comp)
                  Write-Output "$($comp.split('.')[0]) == TestFunc"
                }

                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Using:computer -ScriptBlock ${Function:testFunc} -ArgumentList $using:computer

            }
        }
    }
}

testingWF serverFQDN1,serverFQDN2

#Prints
server1 == TestFunc
server2 == TestFunc
```

---

**Suggestion on how to re-write the above code**

Instead of using a workflow to run a parallel foreach loop, i would recommend replacing the functionality with `-AsJob`.

```
foreach($computer in $computers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock ${Function:RegHomePage} -AsJob
}

# Remove Jobs when done
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Remove-Job
```

Comment: I've tried to remove $ and function word but the script returns the error: The term 'RegHomePage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file.

Comment: @user2978216 see updated answer above along with Suggestion on how to run async jobs.

Answer (score 1):

InlineScript dont support $using:function , try nested workflow [nested work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj574123(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
You can move your function inside `InlineScript` block .
Are you sure that key `-PSComputerName` must have value `$Computers` instead `$computer`

**Adding**

Only one way to call function at inlinescriptblock, it's a put it inside. But may you can use nested workflow to call few times invoke comand. Example nested:

```
workflow Test-Workflow { 
function mess{"get ready"} 
   workflow nest-test{  
   mess 
   } 
nest-test 
} 
Test-Workflow
```

You can also read why you can't use import it to inline script in this tutorial:
[tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj574197(v=ws.11))

Comment: Yes, it must be $computer. Sure I can move function into -ScriptBlock{}. If you can give me an example of how to use remote nested work instead of InlineScript that would be great.